Why my computer cannot display axes by manimgl?
On my computer(win11, python3.11, ManimGL v1.6.1), I tried to do the animation which is plot the sin function by manimgl, these are some of my codes:
axes = Axes((-3, 10), (-1, 8))
axes.add_coordinate_labels()
self.play(Write(axes, lag_ratio=0.01, run_time=1))
sin_graph = axes.get_graph(
    lambda x: 2 * math.sin(x),
    color=BLUE,
)
self.play(
    ShowCreation(sin_graph),
    FadeIn(sin_label, RIGHT),
)
self.play(FadeOut(sin_graph), FadeOut(sin_label))
self.play(Uncreate(axes))

then I found there are no axes and function graph, only label and numbers. Like this:

And there are some warns:
WARNING  Unsupported element type: <class 'svgelements.svgelements.Use'>                                                                   svg_mobject.py:174
(process:16712): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 15:43:46.328: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2401.37.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe' (AUMId `Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App') supports 29 extensions but has no verbs
(process:18792): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 15:43:44.521: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_1.2024.319.300_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe' (AUMId `Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.OutlookforWindows') supports 4 extensions but has no verbs

I read the documentation of manimgl, it said axes are NumberLine mobject, so I tried creating a NumberLine mobject, there are still numbers, no line.
Then I tried copying some codes from the example of the documentation, it still didn't work.
So, How to display the axis? Thanks!
